# DataContractJsonSerializer - deserialize to dictionary

Tags: c#, json, silverlight, datacontractjsonserializer

I want to deserialize a json that I get as result of a REST query (the json string can not be changed) to a dictionary type.
The json string looks something like this:

```
{
 "collection": {
   "useful": true 
   "attributes": {
     "ObjectID": "ObjectID",
     "Name": "Name",
     "FirstID": "FirstID",
     "LastID": "LastID",
     "Count": "5",
     },
   "Type": "Polyline",
   "features": [{
     "attributes": {
        "length": 0.10879009704943393
        "time": 0.3822371137674949,
        "text": "some text",
        "ABC": -2209161600000,
        "Type": "SomeType"
        }
      }]
    }
}
```

I create boolean property for 'useful' and integer for 'count' etc. but I have a problem with the 'attributes'. As you can see, in each section (and per result) I get different 'attributes'.
I need to deserialize them into some generic collection like dictionary or list of   KeyValuePair. the problem is, as stated in msdn (here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx) *"Dictionaries are not a way to work directly with JSON"*.

How can I do it if so?
My application is silverlight 5, .Net 4, VS 2010.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may use Dictionary<string, object> as a type of your attributes property.

Comment: I tried it. this is the exception I get: "The data contract type '...' cannot be deserialized because the member 'Attributes' is not public. Making the member public will fix this error. Alternatively, you can make it internal, and use the InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute on your assembly in order to enable serialization of internal members - see documentation for more details. Be aware that doing so has certain security implications."

Comment: You have to define attributes property in your classes as public

Comment: Sure. this is the property:     
[DataMember(Name = "attributes", IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = true)]
public Dictionary<string, object> Attributes { get; set; }
I get this exception each time I try to deserialize to dictionary, even though the dictionary property is public.

Comment: what kind of json serializer you are using? JSON.NET deserialize jsons like this without any problem.

Comment: I am using DataContractJsonSerializer. as much as I know, this is the only serializer available for silverlight.

Comment: [json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) successfully works wint Silverlight, and even it has PCL version. But for JsonSerializer you can try use JsonObject as a type for your attributes parameter. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of using JsonObject?

Comment: just define your Attributes property as JsonObject instead of proposed Dictionary<string, object>. According [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.json.jsonobject(v=vs.95).aspx) this type asts exactly as dictionary, but has 2 indexers - by string and by int index, so it should helps you to get those annoying attributes ) I hope )